# How to customize a Deep Learning model if the output is one-hot vectors?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a Deep Learning model with TensorFlow and Keras. This is a sequential model for tasks of **Single-Instance Multi-Label**, which is a simplified version of [**Multi-Instance Multi-Label**](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI17/paper/download/14747/14350).

Concretely, the input of my model is an array of fixed length, so it can be represented as a vector like this:

[image: Input]

The output of my model is a sequence of letters, which are from a alphabet with a fixed size. For example, an alphabet of {A,B,C,D} with only 4 possible members. So I can use a one-hot vector to represent each letter in a sequence.

The length of the sequences is variable, but for simplicity, I use a fixed length(equals to that of the longest sequence) to store all sequences.

If the length of a sequence is shorter than the fixed length, the sequence is represented by one-hot vectors(equal to the seuqence's actual length) and zero vectors(equal to the remaining length). For example, *CADB* is represented by a 4 * 5 matrix like this:

[image: Output]

Please note: the first 4 columns of this matrix are one-hot vectors, each of which has one and only one 1 entry, and all other entries are 0s.
But the entries of the last column are all 0s, which can be seen as a zero padding because the sequence of letters is not long enough.

So in one word, the input is a vector and the output is a matrix.

Different from the link posted above, the output matrix should be seen as a whole. So one input vector is assigned to a whole matrix, not to a row or column of this matrix.

My question is : how to customize my deep learning model for this special output, for example:

1. What loss function and accuracy metric should I choose or design?
2. Do I need to customize a special layer at the very end of my model?

Comment: What makes you think this is an uncommon situation? In fact, this is probably one of the most common situation and there are plenty of examples. In short: you need `softmax` activation on the output layer and `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function.

Comment: Hi sebrockm, thanks a lot for your proefessional reply. Actually, I have tried to train my model and got pretty good predicting performance(loss is close to 0 and accuracy is more than 0.9) with testing dataset. But when I output the results, I found the predictions are completely different for the labels. Obviously, the results are pretty bad, although the loss and accuracy look pretty good. That made me think my model is different from conventional ones and maybe I should use some new designs for my model.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your interpretation of the data. Such a good loss and accuracy cannot result in completely different labels *unless* you are interpreting the data incorrectly. For example, make sure that you don't confuse the roles of columns and rows. The link you posted says that one instance can have multiple labels assigned to it. That contradicts your description of one-hot vectors. So, maybe it is not one column, but one row of your matrix that encodes the labels of an instance?

Comment: The link I posted above is a paper about Multi-instance Multi-label task. But my model is for Single-Instance Multi-Label tasks, which is somewhat simpler.  In my model, one instance(an input vector) is assigned to a whole matrix, not only one column or row. Actually, the output is a whole, but it can only be expressed by a set of one-hot vectors because it's a sequence of letters(looks like a set of labels).

Comment: Ok, I got it. You should maybe rephrase your question a little to point that out more clearly. I will file an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sebrockm . I am going to repharse my question with more detailed descriptions. Please give me some time.

Comment: I have edited my question with much more detailed descriptions and more diagrams, can it be reopened?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`softmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/softmax) activation on the output layer and have [`categorical_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/categorical_crossentropy) as the loss function.

However, as you can see in the links above, the problem is that these two functions by default are applied on the last axis (`axis=-1`), while in you situation it is the second last axis (the columns of the matrix) that is one-hot encoded.

To use the right axis, one option is to define your own versions of these functions like so:

```
def softmax_columns(x):
    return tf.keras.backend.softmax(x, axis=-2)

def categorical_crossentropy_columns(target, output):
    return tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(target, output, axis=-2)
```

Then, you can use these like so:

```
model.add(SomeLayer(..., activation=softmax_columns, ...)) # output layer

model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy_columns, ...)
```

One good alternative (in general, not only here) is to make use of `from_logits=True` in the `categorical_crossentropy` call. This effectively makes the softmax built-in into the loss function, so that your model itself does not need (in fact: *must not* have) the final softmax activation anymore. This not only saves work, but is also more numerically stable.

Comment: In Keras, the dimension is specified by (None, Row, Column, Channel). So does **axis=-1** mean the channel axis?

Comment: @BioCoder Keras, as a framework, has no such thing as a "specified dimension". Certain layers have specified input and output shapes. In particular, the input and output shapes of `Conv2D` layers are `(None, Row, Column, Channels)`. So, for those layers, `axis=-1` indeed refers to the channels. You did not mention anything about the layers of your model, so I cannot say anything about it. The only thing that I know for sure (based on your description), is that your very last layer should have an output shape of `(None, 4, 5)`, so `axis=-2` refers to the columns (length 4).

Comment: Yes you right, the output shape is (None, 4, 5). And I have rephrased my question with much more detailed decriptions and more diagrams. Now I believe you can be more clear about my model.

Comment: @BioCoder I've read the update and I addressed that in my answer. Is there any question left or does my answer not work for you?

Comment: I modified my codes as you suggested. Now the accuracy dropped to below 0.1 and the predictions remain bad. I think this makes sense, because the accuracy is consistent with predictions now. So maybe the problem indeed lies partially in the choice of loss function and axis. And maybe the structure of my model needs to be improved in order to achieve better performance. But anyway, your answer is really inspiring, thanks!